# Can you "visit" a chrome-extension when testing with Cypress?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cypress

I'm trying to test my chrome-extension using cypress.io

I can successfully load my extension by adding this to `plugins/index.js`:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, args) => {
    if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
      args.push('--load-extension=../bananatabs/build')
      return args
    }
  })
}
```

I can open my extension's index.html on the cypress browser by navigating to
`chrome-extension://ewoifjflksdjfioewjfoiwe/index.html`

But when I try to "visit" it in a test, like this:

```
context('visit bananatabs', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit('chrome-extension://inbalflcnihklpnmnnbdcinlfgnmplfl/index.html')
    })

    it('does nothing', () => {
        assert(true);
    });

});
```

it doesn't work. page reads:

> Sorry, we could not load:
>   chrome-extension://inbalflcnihklpnmnnbdcinlfgnmplfl/index.html

[In the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit.html#Usage) all the examples use http or https protocols, not chrome-extension.

**UPDATE**

I can see the test page is `http://localhost:54493/__/#/tests/integration/visit.spec.js` and it contains an iframe with the page I'm testing, which uses `chrome-extension://` protocol. I'm not sure that would ever work.

Can this be done?

Comment: Try listing index.html and its resources in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: I can manually open chrome-extension://inbalflcnihklpnmnnbdcinlfgnmplfl/index.html and it works. even in cypress browser. it only doesn't work when navigating it as part of a test

Comment: So did my suggestion work?

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work.

Comment: Here is a plugin that may help you [Test a Web extension with Cypress](https://github.com/ejoubaud/cypress-browser-extension-plugin)

Answer (score 10):

Not Currently, but I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1965) for just that.

Cypress puts an arbitrary restriction for `http`/`https`, and could easily add support for browser specific protocols such as `chrome://`, `resource://`, and `chrome-extension://`

Feel free to throw a :+1: on it!

Comment: Is this available yet?

Comment: any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

To Solve This Issue You can give relative path to the HTML page but the dis-advantage of this is method is that your page will not run in context for chrome extension which means you will not get access to `chrome.storage` and other method ..

```
describe('login credentials', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    let filePath = "/html/popup.html"
    console.log("file Path", filePath)
    cy.visit(filePath);
  })
  it('should login with valid credentials', () => {
    cy.get('#clientCode').clear();
    cy.get('#clientCode').type('AH0405');
    cy.get('#password').type('Ae$HMG$cnZLti5');
    cy.get('#GenerateOtp').click();
    cy.on('window:alert', (message) => {
      // Here, you can perform assertions on the alert message
      expect(message).to.equal('Password verified');

      // You can also simulate clicking "OK" on the alert
      // to dismiss it.
      // cy.on('window:confirm', () => true); // Clicks "OK"
    });
    // Add assertions for successful login
  });
});
```